# Htaccess mod_rewrite: how to change page.php to /page?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Simple question:

domain.com should lead to index.php

and domain.com/lala (or any other word) should lead to products.php?name=lala

Could somebody give me the rewrite rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your `.htaccess` file in web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ products.php?name=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. I am getting a Internal Server Error. Possible mistake inside?